# How do I find the latest BIOS for my MB when the manufacturers provide the wrong file?

Tags: motherboard, bios

I have a BioStar M7NCG 400 7.x motherboard. (The 7.x is important, as it is physically a different board than other versions.) This is a legacy motherboard, but is still supported with official drivers etc.

I'm looking for the latest BIOS for my MB firmware, but all BioStar has listed on their site is the BIOS for their T-Series motherboards, which are clearly newer and completely different. (Listed *in* the section for the M7NCG 400 7.x...) Furthermore, if I try to run the file they provide, the flash utility just freezes, fortifying the theory that they are providing the wrong BIOS for their legacy boards. I've been Googling for a couple hours and I haven't found anything that will tell me what the latest release is.

What are some good places to look for official BIOS files outside of the general manufacturers? And how else can I find out what is really the *latest* BIOS release for this legacy board?

Comment: There are no reason to update a BIOS, unless you experience problem with your PC.

Comment: I haven't said anything about the reasons I have for updating. Please don't jump to conclusions about my situation.

Comment: Can you try to reset the CMOS and try again to flash the BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the BIOS manufacturer (AMI Bios, H2Bios, American Megatrends, etc) website and check for a compatible BIOS (Check North and South bridges, processor, motherboard...)

Keep in mind that flashing BIOS is a really risky task that should be only attempted in case that something with your current one. Personal experience about BIOS flashing: I updated an ASUS K8V-MX motherboard some time ago, and the only new thing I got was support for a new CPU (Athlon 64 3800+, and whats the point from updating a 3400+ to a 3800+?). So you should really consider keeping your current BIOS.